# Can I Upgrade Ubuntu 10.10 to 13.10?

Tags: 10.10

my OS was left to 10.10 and I was unable to upgrade it to 11.04. Is there a way I can upgrade this to the latest version (13)?
thank you.

Comment: Also related [Can I skip over releases when upgrading?](http://askubuntu.com/q/34430/107450)

Comment: 10.10 has not been getting security updates for over a year and a half.  You should format and install 13.10, and upgrade when told the new release is out, since 13.10 will only be supported for 3 months after that.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You can only upgrade from a release to the next release, or from a LTS release to another LTS release.  Since your installation is so old, it would probably behoove you to just reinstall from scratch, rather than perform the time-consuming upgrades one at a time.  See [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/34430/can-i-skip-over-releases-when-upgrading) for a good explanation of why, if you're curious.

Answer (score 1):

you could download the iso and use unetbotin you can install it by typing this in terminal

sudo apt-get install unetbootin

the iso image for Ubuntu 13.10 32-bi can be found at the following link

http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/thank-you?release=latest&bits=32&distro=desktop&status=zeroc

I'm sorry, the link takes up two lines. The iso is Ubuntu 13.10 32-bit, you can make a bootable flash drive or a DVD (use brasero for DVD). I am not familiar with 10.10 because I joined ubuntu when 13.04 came out, but I used 12.04 and others after it. THis should help you out.